# Form guide for behind the neck press

Tags: weightlifting

There are more than ample for normal OHP but none for behind the neck press. In OHP, it was important to squeeze the glutes and keep the arms in the scapular plane.

I am presuming that one would have to also squeeze the glutes when doing it from back, but what about the arm position and bar path? Is there anything to note on that?

Comment: Why do you prefer to do behind the neck over standard?

Comment: I heard it helps grow rear delt. and also, just plain curiosity @DeeV

Comment: It may work your rear delts slightly more than a normal OHP but the cons outway the pros. The benefit to the  rear delts is minimal but it puts you in a more compromised position and reduces the efficacy of the movement for the front delts. All in all, not worth it.

Comment: "In OHP, it was important to squeeze the glutes and keep the arms in the scapular plane." Neither of these things are actually important for the overhead press.

Comment: And the behind-the-neck press does not train the rear deltoids.

Comment: What, if anything, are you not finding on the internet? This is a very basic google search that produces several websites and relevant videos. As Shog9 once said, "We are not trying to replicate google". It would be much better if you came with specific questions about a specific site rather than a generic "What's good form?" which can easily be found.

Comment: @Ethan stop knocking the BTN press, it's a good exercise for many purposes

Comment: @DaveLiepmann - it puts a lot more stress on the delts and rotator cuffs but the difference in the effect of the exercise on the shoulder compared to a standard OHP  are pretty small. What are the benefits?

Comment: @Ethan reinforcing the overhead position and improving mobility. Some people do have goals which are not pure strength and hypertrophy, it turns out

Answer (score 1):

Catalyst Athletics has a detailed form guide for the [press behind the neck](https://www.catalystathletics.com/exercise/204/Press-Behind-The-Neck/):

> Hold the bar behind your neck like a back squat in your jerk-width grip unless you jerk with an unusually wide grip—in that case, hold the bar about half a fist to a fist-width outside the shoulders. Squeeze the upper inside edges of the shoulders blades together tightly and keep the elbows down.

> Pressurize and brace the trunk. Push the bar aggressively with the arms straight up into the overhead position—the trunk will already be leaning forward very slightly and the bar in line with the proper overhead position, so no further movement of either is necessary. Lock the overhead position forcefully.

Significant portions of their material is weightlifting-specific but this strikes me as good advice for the general case. Bar path is "straight up".